# Scala functional kung-fu to internationalize a datatable columns specification?

Tags: json, scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0, datatables

I'm using [Play 2.2.2](http://www.playframework.com/) and the [DataTables JQuery](https://datatables.net/). I have a single list view template that shows a DataTable that gets its columns specification from the server side i.e. column width, column name etc. the replacement happens on the view during server processing. Now I'd like to internationalize the column names with `@Messages` in each Json column specification but of course the server-side processing is over at that time and need to do the internationalization on the server side. To this end I'd like to learn what functional construct could be used to replace all the keys with the corresponding text i.e.

```
{
  "portfolio" : {
    "columns": [
      { "data": "accountName", "title" : "columns.spec.portfolio.account_name", "orderable" : true, "filterable" : true },
      { "data": "securityName", "title" : "columns.spec.portfolio.security_name", "orderable" : true, "filterable" : true },
      { "data": "position", "title" : "columns.spec.portfolio.position", "orderable" : true, "type" : "number" }
    ]
  },
  "price" : {
    "columns": [
      { "data": "securityName", "title" : "columns.spec.price.security_name", "orderable" : true, "filterable" : true },
      { "data": "price", "title" : "columns.spec.price.price", "orderable" : true, "type" : "number", "className": "align-right" },
      { "data": "created", "title" : "columns.spec.price.created", "orderable" : true, "searchable" : false, "filterable" : false, "className": "align-right"  }
    ]
  }
}
```

My `messages` file looks like this:

```
columns.spec.portfolio.account_name=Account Name
columns.spec.portfolio.security_name=Security Name
columns.spec.portfolio.position=Position
columns.spec.price.security_name=Security Name
columns.spec.price.price=Price
columns.spec.price.created=Created
```

My `Application.scala` where I load the DataTable configuration. Here I'd like to replace all the keys with the corresponding text in one go. I have Play's `Messages` but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
  val dataTableConfigurationsFile = play.api.Play.getFile("/conf/dataTableConfigurations.json")
  val dataTableConfigurationsLines = try {
    Source.fromFile(dataTableConfigurationsFile).getLines().mkString("\n")
  } catch {
    case e: FileNotFoundException ⇒
      println(s"File not found: ${dataTableConfigurationsFile.getPath()}."); throw (e)
    case e: IOException ⇒ println(s"Read file failed: ${dataTableConfigurationsFile.getPath()}"); throw (e)
  }
  val dataTableConfigurations = Json.parse(dataTableConfigurationsLines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but works:

```
Json.toJson {
  json.as[Map[String, Map[String, JsValue]]] mapValues { obj =>
    val columns = obj("columns").as[Seq[Map[String, JsValue]]]
    val newColumns = columns map { subobj =>
      val title = subobj("title").as[String]
      val newTitle = Messages(title)
      subobj.updated("title", Json.toJson(newTitle))
    }
    obj.updated("columns", Json.toJson(newColumns))
  }
}
```

I think the developers intended their [JSON transfomers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonTransformers) API for tasks like this, but unfortunately it wasn't made for working on multiple paths at once. Otherwise, something as simple as this would work:

```
val transformer = (__ \\ "title").json.update {
  __.read[String].map(x => JsString(Messages(x)))
}
json.transform(transformer).get
```

Comment: Super nice answer thank you !! Yes I ended up struggling with the second choice but always getting path errors and resulting null on the get. The ugly one is perfect for me :D